# Asp.Net MVC web API forcing UTC conversion on dateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.5

On my API(ASP.Net, .NET Framework 4.5), I need to return datetime in this format: 2020-06-19T13:30:44+00:00

So I created a new converter

```
public class JsonDateFormatConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public JsonDateFormatConverter(string format)
    {
        DateTimeFormat = format;
    }
}
```

And decorated my models:

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonDateFormatConverter), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz")]
    public DateTime? StartDate{ get; set; }
```

But instead of returning the for examle "2020-03-07T00:00:00+01:00" im getting "2020-03-06T23:00:00Z"

So it seems that everything is being converted to UTC before serialization to JSON.

I tried setting this in WebApiConfing

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
```

But that did not help.

Also tried setting the dateTime kind like this:

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonDateFormatConverter), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz")]
    public DateTime? StartDate
    { 
        get => startDate;
        set 
        {
            if (value != null)
                startDate= DateTime.SpecifyKind(value.Value, DateTimeKind.Local);
            else
                startDate= value;
        }
    }

    private DateTime? startDate;
```

Also didnt help.